# GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 error - crashed with 'j.l.NullPointerException' when running Karate Gatling test

Tags: karate

When I try to run a Gatling performance test with Karate, I get the following in the error log.

```
Simulation perf.SVTKarateSimulation started...
17:55:28.277 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2][ERROR][Action.scala:71] c.i.k.g.KarateAction - 'classpath:com/TCEU/KarateTests/Test.feature' crashed with 'j.l.NullPointerException', forwarding to the next one
```

This is how my pom file looks:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <simulationsFolder>src/test/java</simulationsFolder>
                    <includes>
                        <include>perf.SVTKarateSimulation</include>
                    </includes>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And using Karate-Gatling 0.9.5.RC4

This is how my scala file:

```
package perf

import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class SVTKarateSimulation extends Simulation {

  val create = scenario("Get api").exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/TCEU/KarateTests/test.feature"))

  setUp(
    create.inject(rampUsers(10) during (10 seconds)))

}
```

And the test.feature file:

```
Feature: Gatling test

    Background: 
    * url 'https://regres.in'

    Scenario: Get api

        Given path '/api/users/2'
        When method GET
        Then status 200
```

I looked at solutions provided in

[Crashed with 'j.l.NullPointerException' when i try to run karate-gatling test reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821029/crashed-with-j-l-nullpointerexception-when-i-try-to-run-karate-gatling-test-re)

and also
https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/404

But the solutions provided in that does not help either.

I am using Windows 10 with Eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0).

I tried to run another project related feature file but that gave the same error so tried a simple test following a video tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrRhndl-osY

Can someone kindly help please?

Comment: no one can help you unless you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your suggestion. Followed your suggestion and submitted an issue with the project zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else who faces this issue, the solution is to keep your pom.xml consistent with same version of Karate. My karate-gatling was 0.9.5.RC4 where as karate-apache was 0.9.4. When I made them both 0.9.5.RC4, I did not face these issues. Make sure pom.xml is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

And if anyone runs into this kind of issue when compiling / running:

```
15:22:28.250 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - one error found
15:22:28.252 [main] ERROR io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed
sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: null
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:242)
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:111)
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:90)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:133)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
        at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:116)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:307)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:307)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:106)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:87)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:116)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:63)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:89)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:134)
        at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:80)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:67)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:311)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:269)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:159)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:238)
        at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:69)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.doCompile(ZincCompiler.scala:210)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.delayedEndpoint$io$gatling$compiler$ZincCompiler$1(ZincCompiler.scala:215)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$delayedInit$body.apply(ZincCompiler.scala:39)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.main(ZincCompiler.scala:39)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler.main(ZincCompiler.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
```

This is likely to be because on Windows, the Java `bin` folder is not added to the System `PATH`. See the below thread for more details.

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/404#issuecomment-417630286